# Backup strategy in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, database-backups

I have a **single node setup** in MongoDB,

I currently use the `mongodump` which collects the mongo backup and store in another machine. 
But I have a scenario that If my last backup time is 12:00 PM and when the system goes down at 12:55 PM then there will be a data loss from 12:00 PM to 12:55 PM

so what is the best way to have zero data loss.

***NOTE*** : I deployed the mongodb in Docker

Any backup strategy is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

> I have a **single node** setup

There's your problem. If the only node goes down, you *will* lose data (if by "going down" you mean irrecoverable loss of the machine and its storage). To avoid data loss and service interruptions, set up a replica set (possibly distributed between data centers or availability zones).

Comment: Even If I have 3 node setup then I need to worry about two nodes failures in the same time. 

I need the best backup strategy without / minimum data loss in the single node setup itself

Comment: @Harry Have 7 nodes then, across 3 data centers. This setup is nearly impossible to take down. And one node cluster - forget it.

Comment: I understand with the Multi node setup, but I would like to know what is the best way to use the mongodump so that my backup will be safe in the file system

Comment: I am fine with downtime but data loss is the problem for me

Comment: @Harry: rule №1: don't store backups on the same machine. Move them elsewhere. Onto amazon S3, for example. Should be very safe there.  And if you're willing to tolerate downtime, then a single-node setup should not lose (too much) data. Just make sure that journaling is on.

Comment: @Harry: "I am fine with downtime" - but you tagged the question with `[high-availability]`

Comment: is there a way for differential backup in mongodb? So that I don't need to take the complete backup every hour

Comment: this tag is removed, could you explain on differential backup ?

Comment: @Harry Atlas can do it. And cloud manager: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/. But they require a replica set. Maybe they'll be fine with one-node RS, didn't check.